# Upgrade to Rails 5: while saving a record "id" is assigned primary key value instead of a number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, ruby-on-rails-5, mass-assignment

In my table, primary key (my_id) is a string (combination of letters and numbers) and 'id' is a numeric column. Since rails 5 doesn't allow `attr_accessible`, I added the private method to controller `params.require(:model_name).permit(:list_of_attributes)`.
Now when I try to add a new record to this table, "id" takes the value of "my_id" (primary key). I was expecting "id" to be an increment number but this behavior started after removing attr_accessible.
Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@model.attributes["id"] this worked.